# Why does Xcode keep changing its active executable?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, build-process, ios-simulator

Something really weird is going on with Xcode and an iPhone project I'm working on, when I'm building for the simulator, the project has 2 active executables (MyApp - iPhone Simulator (2.0) and MyApp - iPhone Simulator (2.1)) Almost all of the time, I want to use the the 2.1  active executable, but Xcode will occasionally silently change to the 2.0 one.

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to this or any trigger that I can notice. Googling has found a couple of people out there who are having the same problem, but no solutions.

Help me stackoverflow-kenobi! You're my only hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a bug. The good news: it's fixed in the fresh new 2.2 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

That *is* weird -- I've been doing iPhone/XCode development for a while, now, and never seen anything like that.

Are you absolutely certain that you're not poking around some place that's causing the change?

Might you have a corrupt XCode or .xcodeproj?  If it persists, I'd try re-creating my project and, if that didn't help, reinstalling XCode.

Very strange, indeed...!

Comment: This is a client project, and I wasn't around when they created it. The build system is.... "interesting" ... so maybe some setting somewhere is wrong but I haven't been able to find it. Oh and shouldn't that have been a comment instead of an answer Olie?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I need to set the active Executable to 2.1 for openAL to work. The pattern I observed is that it switches back everytime I switch to export to the device. Isn't that what happens with you?

I've seen the issue commented a couple of times on the official iphone dev forum, but no solutions. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score -1):

So.. why are you actually doing that?  It is probably better, given the nature of the iPhone (with multiple frameworks for multiple architectures), to set up different Targets for your various projects.  The executable produced will be the result of the build phases for your targets.